# How do I iterate over a JSON array using Jade and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, templates, pug

So I have this JSON array `apiData` being passed on to the view as `data`.

**Backend**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var data = JSON.stringify(apiData);
    res.render('gallery', { data: apiData });
});
```

**Frontend**

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 MyProject
    !{JSON.stringify(data)}
```

I am trying to cache `!{JSON.stringify(data)}` in a variable and iterate through it in the jade file.  I am completely new to jade.  How could I go about doing this?

Comment: You could use Objects.key(data) and for (k in Objects.key(data)){//access to each value like; data[k];}

Comment: Could you post a link to code at repl.it or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 5):

You have a few problems in your code, like not using the stringification you do server side at all.

But you don't even need JSON here. Simply pass the array and iterate on it :

**Backend**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('gallery', { data: apiData });
});
```

**Frontend**

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 MyProject
        each thing in data
             p= thing
```

You'll find [examples of iteration in the documentation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/)

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work ? Do you have errors ? You'll find many working examples in my public repository miaou, see https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/libs%2Fprefs.js#L145 (server)  and https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/views%2Fprefs.jade#L83 (jade)

Comment: Very mature of you to -1 the question for letting you know your solution doesn't work on my side.

Comment: You're still refusing to tell what doesn't work and what errors you have on the console. You're just making developers willing to help you lose their time... For future questions have a look at the "How to ask questions" page in the help.

Comment: If you are unsatisfied with a comment, perhaps you should leave it with your response, not act like a child going around down voting questions.

Comment: If this is in a jade template, then `p= thing` should probably be `p= #{thing}`. Didn't work for me either until I made that change.