# Parsing JSON within Jade

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

I have a big array of objects that I am passing via express into a Jade template.  It looks like this:

```
[{ big object }, { big object }, { big object }, ...]
```

I pass it into the Jade template by stringifying it:

```
res.render('search-results', {
  data: JSON.stringify(body)
});
```

In my Jade template, I am trying to parse the JSON and iterate over each object within, as follows:

```
each d, i in JSON.parse(data)
  // Do stuff
```

However, `d` is logged as `[object Obj]` when I print it, and I am thus unable to access to object.  When I try to do `JSON.parse(d)`, it also fails because `d` is literally the string "[object Obj]".  I've tried passing the data into the template a bunch of different ways and keep coming up short.  Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need [to stringify the data at all](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28149612/1377002)

Comment: No, I believe I do.  If I don't, then `d` is still logged as `[object Obj]`, and I cannot access any properties.

Comment: You don't need to stringify the data if the data is a valid json object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by doing the following:

When constructing the array of objects on the backend Express-side, I stringified each of the objects inside of the array.  Then, I passed the array of stringified JSON objects to the Jade template, which was consequently able to parse and use the data.

Answer (score 0):

try `each d, i in JSON.parse(data[0])`

Since you send an array of objects you need to go one level deeper to come to the objects.